# Do we need a Dansguardian tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was killing off the [filter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/filter) tag. And found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/316014/169736) but don't know what tag should I use. I found 44 something posts with Dansguardian keyword. So, we have people capable of answering dansguardian's questions? Any volunteer?